# Setting up jdk for ruboto - error

Tags: java, android, ruby, ruboto

I'm following this tutorial here for setting up Ruboto: http://rubylearning.com/blog/ruboto-quick-start/

I got an error setting up system environment variables in my command line in the JDK step. This is the code I typed in and error received:

```
$ path=%path%;c:"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
> classpath=%classpath%;.;
> JAVA_HOME=c:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
sh.exe": c:"Program: command not found
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should surround the whole long pathes with quotes, e. g. :

```
path=%path%;"c:Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin"
```

Hope it helps.